# Auto selecting of drop-down field based of other drop-down list

Tags: c#

There is an  share-point list ( My list ) in that there are 3 column are there ( ID , Name , Address).And i have Designed an custom form in Visual studio in that form there are 3 drop down button [ID],[Name],[Address].
Suppose if user select ID = 1  in 1st drop-down list then Automatically name and address should get selected in name and address drop-down list .

please help me with the .. Thanks in advanced

Comment: bind secondCombobox with respect to the `combo1.SelectedValue`

Comment: i tried but can you tell  me show to do it ? i have used code as below
ddlID.DataValueField = "Title"; // List field holding value
            ddlID.DataTextField = "Title"; List field holding name to be displayed on page

Comment: could you please post the code which binds the combobox2

Comment: Sure
ddlName.DataValueField = "Title"; // List field holding value
ddlName.DataTextField = "Title"; // List field holding name to be displayed on page